# Loop through array of text to create an list of random order with D3 & CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, coffeescript, data-visualization

I have a json file of data, something like the following:

**data.json:**

```
[{
    "name": "Jack"
    "age": 5,
    "quotes":[
    "I want a candy",
    "I want mommy",
    "I want bears"
]},{
    "name": "Jess"
    "age": 4,
    "quotes":[
    "I want a candy",
    "I want daddy",
    "I want dolls"
]},
...]
```

There are a bunch of them, but you get the idea.

So I created a bubble chart with these data. Each bubble is one kid and the size of the kid is represented by the size of the bubble. It's good. It's done.

What I am trying to do the next is that, when you click on the bubble, quotes of the chosen kid appears in a list like this in **index.html**:

```
<ul id="quotes">
   <li>I want a candy.</li>
   <li>I want mommy.</li>
   <li>I want dolls.</li>
</ul>
```

So far, in my CoffeeScript file, **quotes.coffee**, the relevant parts I have are as follows:

```
rValue = (d) -> d.age
idValue = (d) -> d.name
textValue = (d) -> d.name
quotesValue= (d) -> d.quotes

updateQuotes = (id) ->
    if id
      for x in data when idValue(x) is id
        d3.select("#quotes").html("#{quotesValue(x)}")
    else
      d3.select("#quotes").html("<li>Click one to read.</li>")
```

As you can see, the line above `d3.select("#quotes").html("#{quotesValue(x)}")` would not give me the result that I want. I wonder how I can loop through the `quotes` array to get the value to appear in each `<li>` in the `ul#quotes`. Better yet, but totally optional: every time I click on the bubble, I get a list of different order, as opposed to the order based on the `quotes` array. Thanks!

FYI: I found this [very useful snippet about binding nested data with D3](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1219585). I tried to incorporate it into mine unsuccessfully...

```
updateQuotes = (id) ->
    node.classed("selected", (d) -> id == idValue(d))
    lists = d3.select("body").selectAll("ul")
              .data(data, (d, i) -> d.name)
    lists.enter().append("ul")
         .attr("class", (d) -> d.name)
    lists.exit().remove();

    lines = lists.selectAll("li").data((d) ->
      d.quotes
    , (d, i) ->
      console.log d
      d
    )
    lines.enter().append("li")
         .text((d,i) -> d)
    lines.exit().remove()
```

So here I'm just trying to create a new `<ul>` through D3. However, in the console, it says `name` is undefined, which I see why, but how should I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes, I read through that and some other examples, and updated my code.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/vmd0v2sh/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes, it works when it's outside of the function `updateQuotes`, but since mine is wrapped in the function, it doesn't work anymore, because the console tells me that `name` is undefined. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't see why that should be given that you're referencing `name` only inside anonymous functions that are independent of the call context.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yea that's what I thought too but I had similar problems before.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77938/discussion-between-practicemakesperfect-and-lars-kotthoff).